# How to place an image in multiple column layout in HTML CSS?

Tags: html, css

How to place an image in multiple column layout CSS in a HTML page?

Created a html page with contents in article tag. Created css with column-count as 5. I am trying to place an image in the 2nd column spanning to 3rd and 4th column too.

HTML Layout should be

```
texttexttext  ******************************************  texttexttext

texttexttext  ******************************************  texttexttext

texttexttext  ************SINGLE IMAGE************  texttexttext

texttexttext  ******************************************  texttexttext

texttexttext  texttexttext   texttexttext  texttexttext   texttexttext

texttexttext  texttexttext   texttexttext  texttexttext   texttexttext
```

My html code and CSS code are below

HTML Code (just the article tag)
index.html

```
<article>
<img src="http://www.robfraser-photographer.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/SHOT-9.jpg" />
<p> Het was 17 graden onder nul toen het ijs onder onze benen begon te kraken. Consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam. Paragraph Duis autem vel eum
iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
<p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta. nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam.</p>
<p>Paragraph Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore
te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
<p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim
ad minim veniam.</p>
<p>Paragraph Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore
te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
<p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim ass.</p>
</article>
```

My CSS Code
Samp.css

```
article {
  max-width: 860px;
  column-count: 5;
column-gap: 20px;
height: auto;
}
article img {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
column-span: all;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  left: 200px;
  z-index:-1;
  overflow: auto;


}
 article p {
  margin-bottom: 1.3em; 
}
article p:first-of-type {
    position: static;
    float: left;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
article {
          max-width: 860px;
          column-count: 5;
          column-gap: 20px;
          height: auto;
        }
        article img {
          position: absolute;
          display: block;
          column-span: 2;
          height: 200px;
          width: 330px;
          margin-bottom: 25px;
          left: 100px;
          right: 150px;
          z-index:-1;
          overflow: auto;


        }
         article p {
          margin-bottom: 1.3em; 
        }
        article p:first-of-type {
            position: static;
            float: left;
            z-index: -1;
            overflow: auto;
        }
```

Above is the updated CSS file.
Add a right property in article img in CSS and reduce width of the img. Hope this works for you.

Comment: Nope,it is not working. Same problem persist. Text and images are overlapping, unable to get the required layout.

Comment: My code in jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sridhar3525/f0y11kLk/ , kindly check it.